# I tried various cut commands but unable to get the output I desire

Tags: unix, sed, awk, cut

```
cat DecisionService.txt
/MAGI/Household/MAGI_EDG_FLOW.erf;/Medicaid/MAGI_EDG_FLOW;4;4
/VCL/VCL_Ruleflow_1.erf;/VCL/VCL1_EBDC_FLOW;4;4
/VCL/VCL_Ruleflow_2.erf;/VCL/VCL2_EBDC_FLOW;4;4
```

I tried this:

```
cat DecisionService.txt |  cut -d ';' -f2 | cut -d '/' -f2 | tr -s ' ' '\n'
```

My output is:

```
$i=Medicaid
VCL
VCL
```

Whereas I need the output to be:

```
$a=Medicaid
$b=VCL
```

Comment: How do you choose the variable names?  Why are you using `$i=xxxx` notation instead of shell assignment `i=xxxx` notation?  Are you looking for unique names?  Must they be kept in order?  What happens if a name such as VCL appears in lines 2, 3, 5 (with something else in line 4)?  It appears that you want the top-level directory listed after the first semi-colon in the line — is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well from the question, it's not much clear what exactly you want, but i guess you don't want repeated `VCL` in output. Try adding sort and uniq at the end.

```
cat DecisionService.txt
/MAGI/Household/MAGI_EDG_FLOW.erf;/Medicaid/MAGI_EDG_FLOW;4;4
/VCL/VCL_Ruleflow_1.erf;/VCL/VCL1_EBDC_FLOW;4;4
/VCL/VCL_Ruleflow_2.erf;/VCL/VCL2_EBDC_FLOW;4;4

cat DecisionService.txt |  cut -d ';' -f2 | cut -d '/' -f2 | tr -s ' ' '\n'|sort|uniq
Medicaid
VCL
```

Comment: strange, `uniq` should maintain the line separation. How you are treating the output? Try adding another pipe at the end and then feed the data through `xargs`. I tested like `cat DecisionService.txt |  cut -d ';' -f2 | cut -d '/' -f2 | tr -s ' ' '\n'|sort|uniq|xargs touch`. So this created 2 distinct files, `Medicaid` and `VCL`

Comment: cat DecisionService.txt | cut -d ';' -f2 | cut -d '/' -f2 | tr -s ' ' '\n'|sort|uniq|xargs touch -- Gives no output.

Comment: `I tested` it means that I tested that the output comes in separate lines. `touch` does not give anything output. It created empty files in the run directory :) you should replace touch with what you want to do, also be sure to check `xargs` manpage to see how arguments are passed. `xargs` passes each output line separately to the command passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the unique values then:

```
awk -F'/' 'NF&&!a[$(NF-1)]++{print $(NF-1)}' file
Medicaid
VCL
```

If you actually want the output to contain prefixed incremental variables then:

```
awk -F'/' 'NF&&!a[$(NF-1)]++{printf "$%c=%s\n",i++,$(NF-1)}' i=97 file
$a=Medicaid
$b=VCL
```

Note: If your input may contain more than 26 unique value you will need to do something cleverer to avoid output such as `$|=VCL`.

Comment: Thanks but i get this:    awk: (FILENAME=DecisionService.txt FNR=4) fatal: attempt to access field -1

Comment: @iaav then you have empty lines in the file, easily fixed, see update.

Comment: This will work for the posted input but it's better to test `NF` than `$0` when checking for empty records as the latter will fail if the record is populated with a numerical zero. In this case the problem you're trying to avoid occurs due to NF being zero so it seems more natural to test for NF being non-zero anyway.

Comment: @iaav great, you should now accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it, this will show the question as solved.

Comment: lol `you should now accept this answer` :D :D, why not `that` answer :D seems he copy pested same line to all answers. Just kidding. Btw,@sudo_O, seems you are one person where i can expect all my `awk` problems solved. I've been following your awesome awk one liners. great~~

Comment: true, iaav accept whichever answer was of the most use to you. @abasu ha thanks.